# difflibで得られた差分を取り出し、リストのように利用する方法

Tags: python, ms-word

2つのWord文書を比較して差分を取得し、さらにその差分と同じ単語が元の文書内に存在しないかを調べるプログラムを作りたいと思っています。

例えば、Aという元の文書内の"America"という単語を1箇所だけ"Japan"に変更するとして、変更後の文書を文書Bとします。文書Aと文書Bをdifflibを使って比較すると、"-America +Japan"という形で差分が表示されると思いますが、この"America"や"Japan"が文書の中に他にも存在しないかを続けて調べるようなコードは可能でしょうか。
少し調べたところ、difflibの戻り値はジェネレータのため、for文でループさせて得た値は再利用できないということを知りましたが、何か良い方法があればご教示いただきたいと思います。

なお、以下が差分を取得するところまでを書いたものです。

```
import docx
import re
import difflib as diff

def get_text(file_name):
    doc = docx.Document(file_name)
    full_text = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        full_text.append(para.text)
    return str(full_text)


t1 = get_text("file1.docx")
t2 = get_text("file2.docx")

words1 = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b',t1)
words2 = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b',t2)

for i in diff.unified_diff(words1, words2):
    print(i)
```

Comment: 「単語を1箇所だけ」の場合は difflib ではなくても、例えば `[[w1, w2] for w1, w2 in zip(words1, words2) if w1 != w2]` とすると `[['America', 'Japan']]` などの結果が得られます。

Comment: 有難うございます。大変参考になります。
なお、変更は1箇所だけの場合もあるのですが、複数箇所変更（又は追加、削除）もするため、リスト自体が大きく変わってしまう場合もあります。そのように大きな変更がある場合にも差分をリストのような形で取り出すのは難しいでしょうか